# Why is RavenDB storing my DateTime without UTC marker?

Tags: datetime, ravendb, asp.net-web-api

I have a C# object that I am saving to RavenRB (build 1.0.960), the DateTime is UNIVERSAL - but RavenDB stores it as the local time `"Time": "2012-06-12T13:07:39.0000000"`

Then, when I use session.Query().Where()... and pass in a universal time, my objects are not returned... because the comparison it 12 hours (Im UTC+1200) out of whack.

What am I doing wrong??

[EDIT]

Ok - I see what the problem is. I am POST-ing my object (JSON) to the server, and I send it in UTC format (no timezone offset, "2012-06-12T13:07:39.00Z") - and I naively expect Asp.net Web API to deserialize it into an object of UTC Kind - just like it was sent - but not. It is DESERIALIZED to Local server time. This means that when I save the object to Raven, Raven stores it as local time (without the Z identifier). Argh! I want all my dates stored in the database in UTC (as per best practice)!

Trying to hack into the Web API serialization is a real pain. Can Raven save me by some magic flag that will convert all dates to UTC before saving?
I dont want to have to REFLECT over my objects on the server, property-by-property, looking for DateTimes, and converting them to UTC, before saving... EEEW!

Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I have hit a simular gotcha with server timezones.

Comment: I'm assuming that your 'solution' was a nasty hack that you don't wish to speak about publicly? I know mine is (-;

Comment: Ok, I upgraded to the lastest version of ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI (RC) over the weekend. Now I can configure all dates to be serialized and deserialized to/from UTC

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;`

All good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has been fixed by the inclusion of Json.net as the default serializer in ASP.NET MVC 4 RC.
Configure it like this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.D‌​ateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adam,
Check the Time.Kind property, RavenDB should store date time object in UTC as:

```
"Time": "2012-06-12T13:07:39.0000000Z"
```

Note the Z in the end.

Comment: Thanks Ayende - I checked your suggestion, and have amended my question

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman has given a detailed exposition on the pain of [JSON dates in ASP.NET Web Api](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx). It appears they hope to correct the problem before final release. In the meantime he points to a relatively straight forward way to swap out the serialiser to use JSON.NET [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/18/using-json-net-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx).

Comment: Hi - thanks, yeah I'm pretty familiar with the JSON date problem as far as the Web API 'generating' output, but my problem is related to how the Web API ACCEPTS incoming dates. I have changed the serializer to use the Newtonsoft one, however, as you can see in the public code for doing so, it does not apply to IKeyValueModel types, which is what you get during an HTTP POST.